# How to concatenate 2 lists

Tags: python, list, loops, concatenation

list_a : ["http://example.com="]

list_b : [3, 4, 777, 888, 99]

Desired result:

```
['http://example.com=3',
'http://example.com=4',
'http://example.com=777',
'http://example.com=888',
'http://example.com=99']
```

Comment: Did you try something already? Show us what you tried, otherwise you get downvotes and don't learn anything

Comment: Why are you storing the address in a list instead of a `str`?

Comment: Looks like is a list of urls @AdamGold

Comment: "The web address is the same"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Edit

Let's say you have the following lists:

```
list_a = ['http://example.com=']
list_b = [3, 4, 777, 888, 99]
```

Than what you need to do is to create a new list called list_c, and then:

```
for number in list_b:
   list_c.append(list_a[0] + str(number))
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

```
A="http://example.com="
B=[3, 4, 777, 888, 99]
B=[A+str(i) for i in B]
print(B)
```

changed B array using inplace substitution trick of python.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! Can you elaborate on your answer a little bit? For example, explanations about interesting parts of your code snippet, or links to the documentation?